# Firebird trigger translated to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, generator, sequence, firebird

I am converting a Firebird database to MS SQl Server. As there are multiple applications accessing the database, I really want to have the MS SQL Server act in as similar way as possible as to the Firebird database.

In Firebird it is declared as

```
CREATE TRIGGER CUSTOMER_BI FOR CUSTOMER
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
as
begin
  if (new.cust_id is null) then
    new.cust_id = gen_id(gen_cust_id,1);
end
```

So I have a Sequence (Generator in FB) called gen_cust_id
and my main objective is to fill the field cust_id with the nextvalue from the Sequence.

I am very much aware that the SQL Server offers me an autoinc field. This is not really what I am looking for here, as the frontend application(s) do this in various manners. Some of them get a sequence number first and may or may not commit the record. I do in this case just discard the generated sequence number.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I realize I only answered part of your question.  What does "POSITION 0" mean in the firebird syntax?  This looks similar to a SQL trigger, with the exception of that part.

Comment: @CDC position (which is optional) defines the execution order if you have multiple triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Since the ANSI sequence was not implemented until SQL 2012, you should check out this article.  I've used these suggestions to make use of sequences in SQL 2005 - 2008 for a while with great results.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx

So, using option 2 (my preferred), you might have a trigger looking like below.

Note: this only works on a single row insert.  If you want more than 1, you need to modify the example code in the link to give you ranges and do a set-based solution to address each null id row in the inserted "table".

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CUSTOMER_BI 
    ON dbo.CUSTOMER INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sequence_id INT;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE cust_id IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @sequence_id = dbo.GetNewSeqVal_Customer;
    END
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
    (
        cust_id,
        <col list>
    )
    SELECT
        ISNULL(cust_id, @sequence_id),
        <col list>
    FROM INSERTED;
END
```

Comment: You haven't accounted for the `POSITION 0` bit. According to [this](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-trigger.html), it means the order in which the trigger is fired. SQL Server doesn't fully support this but it does allow you to specify a first and a last trigger.

Comment: @AndriyM I'd guess that the `position 0` is likely not relevant (every trigger has a position, even if there is only one for a table or view). The clause is optional when you define the trigger; most tools include it when you ask them to show the DDL.

Answer (score -1):

the position 0 only matters if there is more than one trigger on the table and if there is the mssql side can merge them into 1

Comment: Did you mean this as a response to my comment? You shouldn't have posted this as an answer if so.